# Ansible syncronous poll using the configuration file

Tags: ansible

```
 By default tasks in playbooks block, meaning the connections stay open until the task is done on each node.
```

This may not always be desirable, or you may be running operations that take longer than the SSH timeout.

```
 To avoid blocking or timeout issues, you can use asynchronous mode to run all of your tasks at once and then poll until they are done
```

below is the example.

---

```
- hosts: all
  remote_user: root

  tasks:

  - name: simulate long running op (15 sec), wait for up to 45 sec, poll every 5 sec
    command: /bin/sleep 15
    async: 45
    poll: 5
```

As all my tasks in my playbooks have individual async time so I don't Want to specify the async time 
But I want to specify single poll time for all the tasks in all the playbooks is there a configuration we can set in ansible.cfg file for the poll?

Answer (score 1):

Below is the setting you can configure in ansible.cfg to make it common for all of the playbooks. If present then uncomment it otherwise make a separate entry under defaults. Refer to Sample ansible.cfg.

```
poll_interval = 15
```

> For asynchronous tasks in Ansible (covered in Asynchronous Actions and
>   Polling), this is how often to check back on the status of those tasks
>   when an explicit poll interval is not supplied. The default is a
>   reasonably moderate 15 seconds which is a tradeoff between checking in
>   frequently and providing a quick turnaround when something may have
>   completed.

[Ansible Documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/intro_configuration.html#poll-interval)

[Sample Ansible.cfg](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ansible/ansible/devel/examples/ansible.cfg)